# How many subsets are there of the set $\{3,5,7,8,11,53\}$ that must contain the number $11.$

Tags: probability

> How many subsets are there of the set $\{3,5,7,8,11,53\}$ that must contain the number 11.

Please answer step by step. Please

Comment: Hi, my professor posted this question and I copy-pasted it as it is. I don't really understand the logic behind the question. The solution provided for this question is: Our set is {3,5,7,8,11,53}
If we are considering the subsets that must contain the element 11, then effectively we are looking for all
possible subsets of the set {3,5,7,8,53}, and then add element 11 to each.
This new set has 5 elements so there are 25
 = 32 subsets, and thus 32 corresponding subsets of our original
set that also contain an 11.

Comment: Do you understand this?:  " If we are considering the subsets that must contain the element 11, then effectively we are looking for all possible subsets of the set {3,5,7,8,53}, and then add element 11 to each."  (Not sure how to make that any clearer.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is equivalent to counting the number of subsets of $\{3,5,7,8,53\}.$ This is because each of these subsets will not contain the number $11$ and we can simply add $11$ to each subset so that it becomes a distinct subset of $\{3,5,7,8,53\}$ that contains $11.$ For each of the $5$ elements in $\{3,5,7,8,53\},$ we may or may not include it in the set, so we have a total of $2^5$ subsets, and our answer is $2^5$ or $32.$

Answer (score 1):

Half of the subsets of $A=\{3,5,7,8,11,53\}$ contain the number eleven, and the other half do not. So, the number of subsets of $A$ that contain the number eleven is the same as the number of subsets of $A \setminus \{11\}=\{3,5,7,8,53\}$, which is $2^5=32$. The probability is $\frac{1}{2}=50\%$.

Comment: he just asked how many subsets there are, not the probability

Comment: How precisely do you know that half the subsets have $11$ and half do not?

Answer (score 1):

If $A \subset \{3,5,7,8,53\}$ let $B_A = A \cup \{11\}$.

Claim:  $B_A\subset \{3,5,7,8,11,53\}$ and $11 \in B_A$.

Pf:  ... well what do you think.....

If $B\subset \{3,5,7,8,11, 53\}$ and $11\in B$ then let $C_B = B\setminus\{11\}$.

Claim:  $C_B \subset \{3,5,7,8,53\}$ and $B= C_B \cup \{11\}$.

Pf:  ... well, what do you think.....

So $B \subset  \{3,5,7,8,11, 53\}$ with $11 \in B \iff  B = A\cup \{11\}$ for some $A\subset \{3,5,7,8,53\}$.

So for even $B \subset  \{3,5,7,8,11, 53\}$ with $11 \in B$ there is *exactly* one subset $A\subset \{3,5,7,8,53\}$ so that $B= A\cup\{11\}$.

SO there are *exactly* as many subsets $B \subset  \{3,5,7,8,11, 53\}$ with $11 \in B$  and there are $A\subset \{3,5,7,8,53\}$.

And there are $2^5$ subsets of $\{3,5,7,8,53\}$.

(Remember:  If a set $S$ has $k$ elements, the $S$ has $2^k$ subsets.)